# Creating MS-Access user registration database with online form

Tags: ms-access, registration, online-forms

I would like to know if a microsoft access form can sort information into specific tables based on a selection made with a drop down menu.

**For example:** 
I want to make a database for a group of workshops I am offering with a form users can fill out online. Each workshop has its own table to collect user information (name, email, address etc.) that I can use to create individual reports from for internal company uses. As the user information is the same for each workshop, I ideally want just one form that users can fill out and choose which workshop they want to register for using a drop down menu rather than having to create a registration form for each workshop. This form I would like to integrate into my webpage.

Can access use this drop down menu to record the data into the specific workshop table? Or would I need one table that gathers the information entered by the user that will then transer the data to the workshop specific table via table relationships?

Is there a better way? I have no programming knowledge and am curious to see whether Access can handle a project like this.

Comment: you can write whatever code you want behind the form to intercept/mangle/store the data however you want. but why should ever workshop have its own table? presumably they would ALL have the same information, in which case you only need one table, with one extra field to identify the actual workshop.

Answer (score 0):

As a big part of your question is handling a web interface, you'd want to probably use a HTML form with an ASP.NET page(backend) to connect to the Access database, but make sure it's secure.  I would read up on file permissions and parameterized queries.

To filter by workshop, as Marc B suggested, I would just create a column called workshop and have the value they selected going to that column.  Otherwise, you'll constantly be creating new tables.